# Configure: error: Package requirements (libcanberra-gtk3 >= 0.10) were not met [but libcanberra-gtk3 v. 0.30 is installed]

Tags: yum, configure

I'm trying to build a package (mate-power-manager) and hit this error during `./autogen.sh`:

```
checking for CANBERRA... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libcanberra-gtk3 >= 0.10) were not met:

No package 'libcanberra-gtk3' found
```

However, `yum list libcanberra-gtk3` shows it's installed:

```
Installed Packages
libcanberra-gtk3.i686             0.30-5.el7                        @base    
libcanberra-gtk3.x86_64           0.30-5.el7                        @anaconda
```

Having hit this somewhere in the past, I know a development pacakge is often needed in this case.  So, I've tried checking for `libcanberra-gtk3-dev` and `libcanberra-dev` but they don't exist.

How can I find the package I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pkg-config` is specifically looking for the `.pc` file (in this case `libcanberra-gtk3.pc`)

So, to find out what package provides that file, use `yum whatprovides`:

```
$ yum whatprovides -q '*libcanberra-gtk3.pc'
libcanberra-devel-0.30-5.el7.i686 : Development Files for libcanberra Client Development
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libcanberra-gtk3.pc



libcanberra-devel-0.30-5.el7.x86_64 : Development Files for libcanberra Client Development
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libcanberra-gtk3.pc
```

So, the package needed uses a "devel" suffix, not a "dev" one.  (The `dev` suffix is common to deb/apt, but rpm/yum uses `devel`)